# Multiphase Form (wizard) show all information before submit

Tags: javascript, html

I create a multiphase form (wizards from) and I want to show in the last step all Information in input text (you can modify it) before validate

I try a lot but without any result, how can I do it ?

My code

```js
var fname, lname, age;

function _(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);  
}

function processPhase1(){
    fname = _("firstname").value;
    lname = _("lastname").value;
    if(fname.length > 2 && lname.length > 2){
      _("phase1").style.display = "none";
      _("phase2").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {alert("Please Enter All Information");}
}

function processPhase2(){
    age = _("age").value;
    if(age.length >= 1){
      _("phase2").style.display = "none";
      _("show_info").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {alert("Please Enter All Information");}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="phase1">
    First Name : <input id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
    Last Name : <input id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
    <button onclick="processPhase1()">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="phase2">
    Age : <input id="age" name="age"><br>
    <button onclick="processPhase2()">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="show_info">
    First Name : <input id="firstname" name="firstname" value = ""><br>
    Last Name : <input id="lastname" name="lastname" value = ""><br>
    Age : <input id="age" name="age" value = ""><br>
    <button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
  </div>
```

I try this but it's just for showing Information, but you can't modify it, I need to show it in input text

```js
function processPhase2(){
    age = _("age").value;
    if(age.length >= 1){
      _("phase2").style.display = "none";
      _("show_info").style.display = "block";
      _("display_fname").innerHTML = fname;
      _("display_lname").innerHTML = lname;
      _("display_age").innerHTML = age;
    }
    else {alert("Please Enter All Information");}
}
```

```html
<div id="show_info">
  First Name : <span id="display_fname"></span><br>
  Last Name : <span id="display_lname"></span><br>
  Age : <span id="display_age"></span><br>
  <button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done this completely different, but this is how you would do it based on what you've already written. When you click the next button in each function, you want to grab that value of (`fname`, `lname`, or `age`) and set the value of that to the value of the last set of inputs. I've altered your code a bit and made you a `JS BIN` http://jsbin.com/sopikuzuri/edit?html,output

**In simple terms**


Each time you call a *new phase function (processPhase1)*, you want to grab the values of what the user just entered.


Then, you want to set those values to the proper `<input />`


So, the simplest example I can give is this:

Below, the user will enter some data into the field. When they click the `submit phase 1 button` we will grab the value of what they just entered and set that value to the last input (for them to see/edit)

```
<input type="text" id="firstName"/>
<button id="submit">Submit Phase 1</button>

<input type="text" id="displayInput"/>
<script>
     $("#submit").click(function() {

          // getting the value of what the user typed in
          var fname = $("#firstName").value;

          // setting the value of the final box to the var above
          $("#displayInput").val(fname);

     });
</script>
```

Comment: It's work perfectly, but if you can explain that and use a simple words, because I'm beginner in English language

Comment: @saadsaad I just revised the answer

Comment: This's very perfect but I have in my code ( checkbox, radio, select ) how I can show this value in my code I try without result :'(

Comment: I find the method about select, I need radio and checkbox

Comment: @saadsaad Not sure I understand. You can't figure out how to get the value of your radio and checkbox elements?

Comment: show this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974794/show-result-taked-with-javascript-in-html-code-radio-checkbox

Comment: first I show I form to user and he can check any things he likes, and the second I show it other form that has all information that has insered if he want to modify and finally save it, So the problem I have it in the second part because he is check for example a button radio yes, I ned to check yes automatically in the second part